# Trying to find a way to get total tracks played on an album using time from another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. One has the total time an album was played in seconds. The other has the Album list with numbered tracks and song lengths in seconds.

I need to show only the tracks that were played over half of their total time. For example if Album 1 was played for 130 secs and each track is 60 seconds in length. Then the result would be only Tracks 1 and 2.

EDIT:
Also the results will show all tracks played

Tables

**Tracks**

```
id  |name                |   album| length  |track
1   Happy Boys and Girls    1         60    1
2   My Oh My                1         60    2
3   Barbie Girl (Radio)     1         60    3
4   Cartoon Heroes (Radio)  2         60    1
5   Around the World        2         60    2
6   Freaky Friday           2         60    3
7   Playmate to Jesus       3         60    1
8   Dirty Little Pop Song   3         60    2
9   Myself                  3         60    3
10  Public Service          4         60    1
11  My Name Is              4         60    2
12  Guilty Conscience       4         60    3
```

**Albums**

```
id  |album     |    watched            
1   Aquarium       130
2   Aquarius       100
3   Megalomania    180
4   Slim Shady     170
```

**Results needed from query**

```
id  |name                |  album   |length|    track
1   Happy Boys and Girls    1         60    1
2   My Oh My                1         60    2
4   Cartoon Heroes (Radio)  2         60    1
7   Playmate to Jesus       3         60    1
8   Dirty Little Pop Song   3         60    2
9   Myself                  3         60    3
10  Public Service          4         60    1
11  My Name Is              4         60    2
```

Comment: Please provide source data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (the best way - cteate a fiddle like one in my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte AS ( SELECT a.id album_id, 
                a.len, 
                t.id track_id,
                SUM(t.len) OVER (PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY t.id) cum_len
         FROM albums a
         JOIN tracks t ON a.id = t.album_id )
SELECT DISTINCT 
       album_id,
       COUNT(track_id) OVER (PARTITION BY album_id) played_fully
FROM cte
WHERE len >= cum_len
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=78828a93ce5d3d8c2c9b49c63b3762d6)

Comment: Thank you so much for looking at this. It is just what i asked for! I did add an edit that will hopefully clear up my vagueness. Also for some reason im getting errors when I try your query in Sequel Pro. Weird it shows version 5.7.26 but i am using MySQL version 8.0.21.

Comment: @wm176 *im getting errors* Always provide complete and inchanged error message. *it shows version 5.7.26 but i am using MySQL version 8.0.21.* Actual Sequel Pro version is release-1.1.2 which was released on Apr 3, 2016 whereas MySQL 8.0.0.dmr was released on Aug 25, 2016. There is no surprise that your client version cannot successfully work with recent server version - they aren't compatible, cilent cannot know about features released after its release... For to use MySQL 8+ you **must** use another, more recent, instrument.